# Pnp searchresult should display only the pages of my Communicationsite and not all of them

Tags: sharepoint-online

Pnp searchresult should display only the pages of my Communicationsite and not all of them.
is that possible?

I have added the Query template but i did not work:

```
{searchTerms} IsDocument:1 –
Fileextension:aspx – 
Path:"xxxxxxxxx"
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "my communication site", does it mean only specific site collection where you know URLs or from all communication sites?

Comment: I went to the portal.office.com and a press the button Make Site. I have chosen the Communication site. And made a few pages within that site. I hope i have explained it well

Comment: and in query for Path:"xxxxxx" you mentioned same site URL. correct?

Comment: yes in the path i have specified the url of my site

Comment: could you share screenshot of pnp search result web part property pane where you configured this query?

Comment: I have posted a screenshot. The result is that the query gives nothing in return I have an empty pnpsearchresult. And it should show me the pages of my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwer was just put the path of the site in the Query

Comment: You can mark this answer to close the thread if this issue has been resolved.